# Configuring JSPM to load e.g. "index.js" if no file is found/specified?

Tags: package-managers, jspm

How would I make JSPM try to find an `index.js` if no file is found in the specified directory? For example, if I have `require('../components/my-component')`, and a directory structure like this:

```
app
└ components
  └ my-component
    └ index.js
      my-component.js
      other-js-to-include.js
```

Say I have `index.js` set up to export `my-component` and `other-js-to-include`. With this directory structure, `require` finds `index.js` correctly, but JSPM errors when I try to bundle with a 'no such file or directory' error pointing to `../components/my-component.js` (rightfully so, since that file doesn't exist).

My current solution is to modify `System.config.paths`:

```
  paths: {
    "components/*": "components/*/index.ts"
  }
```

However, this means I need an index file for every component, instead of just the ones where I want to export multiple files.

I realize I could also just be specific when importing (i.e. import `index.ts` directly when I need it), which I might end up having to do, but I wanted to know if there was a way to do this.